# On a proposition of Engelking's General Topology

Tags: general-topology, filters

Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F'}$ be filters on a set.
We say that $\mathcal{F'}$ is finer than $\mathcal{F}$ if $\mathcal{F'} \supset \mathcal{F}$.

A point $x$ of a topological space $X$ is called a cluster point of a filter $\mathcal{F}$ if $x$ belongs to the closure of every member of $\mathcal{F}$.

Is the following assertion in Engelking's book General Topology (1989) p.52 true?

**(Part of)Proposition 1.6.8**
If $x$ is a cluster point of a filter $\mathcal{F}$, then $x$ is a limit of a filter $\mathcal{F'}$ that is finer than $\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Let $\mathcal F'$ be the filter generated by the union of $\mathcal F$ and the neighborhood filter of $x$.  The assumption that $x$ is a cluster point of $\mathcal F$ ensures that this $\mathcal F'$ is a proper filter.